# WAMP 2.5 error! 403 forbidden laravel error for script files in public folder

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

Hello I just started learning laravel, watched a tutorial on how to install it.And it worked. But when I trying to link script files getting error  403 forbidden. The script files I placed in public/script/ folder.
The following error when I trying to access script.
In my html file given.

```
<script src="{{ HTML::script('scripts/jquery-1.11.0.min.js') }}"></script>
```

And the error is

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Forbidden</h1>
<p>You don't have permission to access /laravel/{{ HTML::script('scripts/jquery-1.11.0.min.js') }}
on this server.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.4.9 (Win32) PHP/5.5.12 Server at 127.0.0.1 Port 80</address>
</body></html>

In httpd.conf

<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: In my httpd.conf  <Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all granted
</Directory>

Comment: It looks like your view isn't parsing the `{{ }}`. Have you saved your view as a blade template? e.g. instead of `someview.php` it should be `someview.blade.php`

Comment: Still getting the error. Html is                                   
       
        <script src="{{ HTML::script('public/scripts/jquery-1.11.0.min.js') }}"></script>
        
When I try to access script getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

1. Why are you using HTML 2.0 as a spec?
2. What are your your routes?
3. Have you configured any special .htaccess rules? if so, what are they?

I strongly recommend you follow along with these video's and learn the basics:

https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch